# Unable to get API data in NgFor loop

Tags: angular

I create a little app that bring data from .Net core API & later show off through Angular frontend in browser. Everything work perfect until i see data in console log. But Im unable to bring this API onto fronten which is Angular. I actually fetch this data through NgFor loop.

What I get is:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

my codes are:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'accounting-app';

  constructor(public apiService: ApiService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
    this.apiService.getData();
  }
 }
```

api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
 export class ApiService {

  messages: any = [];

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/weatherforecast').subscribe(res => {
      this.messages = res;
    });
  }
}
```

App.component.html

```
<h1>Weather App</h1>
<h4 *ngFor = "let message of apiService.messages">
    {{message}}
</h4>
```

Comment: the message is an object you should display its attributes separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<h1>Weather App</h1>
<h4 *ngFor = "let message of apiService.messages">
    {{message | json}}
</h4>
```